# How to set a Rails model's instance properties with a method call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a controller that instantiates a model and then calls a method to build associations. I tried to use this method to also set the properties of the model, but it didn't work and I'm wondering why.

here is my code:

```
#my controller
user = User.new  
user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
debugger

#my model
def apply_omniauth(omniauth)  
   email=omniauth["extra"]["user_hash"]["email"]
   name=omniauth["extra"]["user_hash"]["name"]
   authentications.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'],:uid => omniauth['uid'])
end 

#irb
rails:6ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > user.name
=> nil
```

When I set the properties from the controller, then it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
self.name=omniauth["extra"]["user_hash"]["name"]
```

The way you are setting `name` is actually setting a local variable called `name` in the `apply_omniauth` method. It's not a reference to the `name` attribute of the model. To assign to the model's `name` attribute, you need to access it using `self.name`

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the `write_attribute(email, 'foo@bar.com')`. This circumvents any overwritten attribute setters.